# Double integral multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, mathematica

Consider the following integral $$\int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^{1-x_1} dx_2 \, (1-x_1-x_2)^{-\epsilon-1} (-sx_2 - x_1p_1^2)^{-\epsilon-1}$$ where $s$ and $p_1^2$ are to be treated as constants throughout the integration and $\epsilon$ is a real number.

This calculation cropped up midway in a physics calculation and I could not immediately see a way to integrate it.  I subsequently put it in to Mathematica and, much to my surprise, after fifteen mins it is still running a finished evaluation of it. I have kept Mathematica running in the meantime but was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to progress with the integral on a more analytic level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried $$\int _0^1 dx_1\int _0^{1-x_1}dx_2 \to \int _0^1 dx_1\int _0^{1-x_1}dx_3$$ with $x_3=1-x_1-x_2$, and change the order of integral of $x_1$ and $x_3$ so that it is $$\int _0^1 dx_3\int _0^{1-x_3}dx_1 \left(x_3(-s(1-x_1-x_3)-x_1p_1^2)\right)^{-\epsilon-1}$$and Mathematica can do it now$$=-\int _0^1dx_3\left(\frac{(x_3-1)\left(s(x_3(x_3-1)s)^{-\epsilon-1}-p_1^2(x_3(x_3-1)p_1^2)^{-\epsilon-1}\right)}{(s-p_1^2)(-\epsilon)}\right)$$
Hope it will help

Comment: Many thanks, the final integral evaluates to beta functions and the final result has a $s \leftrightarrow p_1^2$ symmetry which is what I expected. I just wanted to check the Jacobian of the transformation though - I keep getting $-1$. The transformation is $$x_1 = x_1\,\,\,,\,\,\,x_3=1-x_1-x_2$$ but computing the Jacobian matrix I get a determinant of -1: $$J = \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_2} - \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1} = (1 \cdot -1) - (0 \cdot -1) =  -1$$ Is there a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: @CAF I think it is correct, and $$\int _0^{1-x_1}dx_2=-\int_{1-x_1}^0dx_3=\int _0^{1-x_1}dx_3$$

Comment: Ah yes, but actually I just realised the change of variables presciption is $$\text{d}x \text{d}y = |J| \text{d}u \text{d}v,$$ taking the modulus of $J$ so wouldn't this mean I still have a minus error? Thanks!

Comment: @CAF I think the $|J|$ means matrix determinant? In fact, I often meet this integral as the result of Feynman parameter which is $$\int _0^1dx\int _0^{1-x}dy=\int _0^1dx\int _0^1dy\int _0^1dz\delta (1-x-y-z)$$ on the  r.h.s., it is free to do the substitution $x<->y$, $x<->z$, $y<->z$, and no sign changes.

Comment: Yes, and indeed what I had to begin with was what you wrote on the rhs there and I simplified it to the lhs. Although the formula above is just a identity yes? I checked the prescription and it seems like I do have to take the modulus of J in this formula so, as far as I can see, it seems like I have a minus mistake. It's been a while since I've used these manipulations but I am wondering why I can't just write the jacobian as $$J = \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} - \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_2} = 1?$$

Comment: I think it is precisely this arbitrariness in the way one can write down the ordering of the jacobian matrix elements that by taking the modulus of the result, this arbitrariness leads to consistent final results (I think :) )

Comment: @CAF on the r.h.s. it is equivalent to do $y->z$, and then $x->z$, which leads to $$\int _0^1dz\int _0^1dx\int _0^1dy\delta(1-z-x-y)$$ and then simplify as $$\int _0^1dz\int _0^{1-z}dx$$ The first Jocobian is correct. It is for the first step ($y->z$) is just a one variant substitution, which can easier written as $$\int _0^{1-x}dy=\int _0^{1-x}d(1-x-z)=\int _{1-x}^0d(-z)$$ and I think it is not modulus but a matrix determinant. The next Jacobian I think you want to do the 2 substitution 1 time, but it is a little confuse about region, you can do it on r.h.s with regions are all $0\to 1$.